# Good 3D simulator for outdoor autonomous navigation

Tags: navigation, simulator, cameras

What's an appropriate tool for simulating a car driving in a simple closed-loop racetrack? I'm trying to implement the control logic for an autonomous vehicle, and I'd like to be able to first simulate the behaviour before testing on a physical platform. The target environment is mostly 2D, but there are some 3D obstacle like small ramps and arches, so I can't use a strictly 2D simulator.

I've looked at some robotics simulators, as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533321/robotics-simulator), but they seem like overkill and none of them seemed designed to model outdoor environments. I've done a little work with Gazebo, and I can't find any guide of texturing the ground/sky/background.

All I really need is some way apply a texture map to the ground and sky, create a handful of obstacles, and then to calculate a camera feed as a simple two-wheeled chassis moves along a mostly 2D course. However, I need the video input to be as realistic as possible because I don't have access to the real world racetrack. I need to be able to test and train the control logic in the simulator, and then load that logic onto the real mobile platform and have it navigate the course.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to work my colleague did on high-speed vehicle control.  He used [TORCS](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/) (The Open Race Car Simulator).  See [this](http://www.irobot.com/dynamo/simulated-high-speed-vehicle-control.php) project page for a video, screenshots, and the published paper of his work.

Answer (score 0):

[ZeroSim](https://github.com/fsstudio-team/ZeroSimROSUnity) is an Open Source robotics simulation toolkit using Unity and ROS integration.  There are is an example with differential drive autonomous robot, but no examples yet of a Ackerman steering controller -- though Ackerman steering shouldn't be too hard to implement.  Because ZeroSim is using Unity it should be quite a bit easier to develop 3D environments then Gazebo and maybe even use one of the many examples of automobiles available via the Unity Asset Store or freely available elsewhere.

Disclosure:  I am a developer for ZeroSim.